# Calculate based on column name and grab the name as part of the calculation

Tags: python, pandas

I need to calculate a difference based on the column name and use part of the column name as part of the calculation.

[image: Data frame]

So currently, the columns the value for the promotions are empty. I need to calculate for the first row get2for30 would be (X-30) and for the second column GET2FOR31  (x-31) and show the values in the respective "cell." 
I wanted to know if there is a way to do it using pandas.

Update - another issue that I had is that the Get2forX's columns go up to 90 so the last column is get2for90. I wanted to know if there is something like a function to apply to all these types of columns. (Without writing 90 lanes of code)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this:-

```
df['GET2FOR30'] = df.Prices - 30
df['GET2FOR31'] = df.Prices - 31
...
```

Or for big number of columns:-

```
cols = df.columns
initial = 30
for i, j in enumerate(cols[2:]):
    if 'GET2FOR'in j:
        df[j] = df.Prices - (i + initial)
```

Comment: To apply the way for the big number of columns I have to use lambda? (I am still a beginner in pandas) or how exactly should I apply to all the columns.

Comment: @Seph77 this applies for all columns the way you want. Anything else?

Comment: This is amazing! it works Is there any chance to apply this only for columns that have the 'GET2FOR'?

Comment: @Seph77 Yes, when you iterate over the columns list, just check whether they have 'GET2FOR' substring or not. See the edits

Comment: @Seph77 also you can accept this answer if satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Would something as simple as this work?

```
df['GET2FOR30'] = df['Prices'] - 30
df['GET2FOR31'] = df['Prices'] - 31
df['GET2FOR32'] = df['Prices'] - 32
```

for a generic N columns:

```
for col in [i for i in df.columns if 'GET2FOR' in i]:
    num = col[col.rindex('FOR')+3:]
    df[col] = df['Prices'] - int(num)
```

Comment: Hi! It will, but another issue that I had is that the Get2forX's columns go up to 90 so the last column is get2for90. I wanted to know if there is something like a function to apply to all these types of columns. (Without writing 90 lanes of code)

Comment: @Seph77 edited answer to make it generic for n columns

Comment: This worked too! But how can I insert elseif here to apply a different calculation? Let say that for column 'GET3FOR' do df['Prices'] - int(num) + 1 (random example)

Comment: @Seph77 you can specify them in if elif statements.